# CSS Spritesheet Animation fill-mode forwards with steps ends on wrong position?

Tags: css

The following snippet should play frames 1-3 three times and (in my opinion) end on frame 3, instead it displays frame 4 after finishing, which is not animated in the 3 iterations before.

Since this works the same in Chrome, Safari & FF, I can only ask: "How can this be correct behavior?" Background offsets are: 0px, -50, -100, -0, -50, -100, -0, -50, -100, -150px

In any case it seems impossible to play an animation-sequence n-times and end on its last frame that was part of the previous 3 iterations.

**Is there a way to parametrize this animation to end on the desired frame after it finishes?**

Desired results can be parametrized for one iteration and infinite iterations, but nothing inbetween.

**For now I assume it is impossible. This seems to be an unintended result of how W3C specified the steps() function and fill-mode.**

https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/136

```css
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
    animation: play 3s steps(3) 3 forwards;
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -150px; }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png" />
<div id="x7" class="hi"></div>
```

Ref: http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/

Answer (score -1):

Change your css.

```
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
    animation: play .8s steps(10);
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

This works perfectly.

Comment: I am **NOT** looking for infinite animations! This is the code from my reference.

Comment: You have also removed fill-mode forwards, which is part of my question. Your example only works because the background warps. Try this: background-repeat: no-repeat; animation: play .8s steps(10) 3 forwards;